# Image not loading inside ng-repeat in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, image, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am facing a weird issue with loading a newly added image to Image tag inside `ng-repeat`. The code works fine with Chrome but IE is not supporting the image loading.

When a user uploads an image to a server location I am getting the location of the image and passing it to `ng-src` but it seems like this is not working with Internet Explorer. I am getting an image as shown below, but when I refresh the page it's loading the image from server location without any issues. Mine is a Single page application so I cannot refresh the page. Could someone please help resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

**Html Code:**

```
 <div id="contactInfoContainer" ng-repeat="contacts in contactData | filter: contactFilter | orderBy:orderByField :!reverseSort |orderBy:'DisplayOrder' | emptyToEnd:'DisplayOrder' ">
            <div class="container1">
                <div class="contactImgContainer image-cropper-main" >
                    <img id="contactImage" ng-src="{{ contacts.ProfileImage.Url || '../Images/person.png' }}" class="contactImg" width="65px" heigth="65px"/>
                </div>
        </div>
```

**IE Console Reference:**

```
<img width="65" class="contactImg" id="contactImage" src="http://TestServer/SiteAssets/ContactImages/sam-killermann-headshot.jpg" ng-src="http://TestServer/SiteAssets/ContactImages/sam-killermann-headshot.jpg" heigth="65px">
```

**Picture Error **

[image]

Comment: Can you share fiddle or plnkr of the same ?